# Implementation Of INotifyPropertyChanged In C# 6.0 - Why No Results?

Tags: c#, viewmodel

So I have bound a property in the ViewModel to a property in a TextBox and I am using an implementation of **INotifyPropertyChanged** for notifications to be raised in the appropriate place. However, I am not seeing data being updated in the TextBox. Where is my error?

```
// ViewModel
namespace App1
{
    public class Result
    {        
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        public string Results
        {
            get { return sb.ToString(); }
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return sb.Length;
        }

        public ResultViewModel()
        {
            dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        }

        public async Task Clear()
        {
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => sb.Clear());
        }

        public async Task Add(Result result)
        {
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => sb.Append(result.Message));            
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Results));
        }
    }
}
```

**Add** gets called by a function in MainPage.xaml.cs as follows...

```
private async void ShowResult(Result result)
{
    await this.ViewModel.Add(result);
}
```

As for **TextBox** looks like this...

```
// XAML
<TextBox x:Name="content"
                     Margin="0,10,0,10"
                     RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.Below="header"
                     RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.Above="genButton"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.Results, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     TextChanged="content_TextChanged"/>
```

Comment: Your binding uses the mode `OneWay`. Are you sure about which "way" that binding goes?

Comment: Who is calling the `Add()` method? You should trigger the `OnPropertyChanged("Results");` instead of `[CallerMemberName]` You're assuming that the caller is the property, but the correct (property)name might not be passed.

Comment: The correct information is being passed into Invoke and UpdateSourceTrigger points to PropertyChanged and Mode is now TwoWay, yet I am still not getting data in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

As @JeroenvanLangen, already said the signature of `Add` doesn't make sense.

Instead you can rise notifications specifying affected by method properties names:

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Results));
```

The syntax with `CallerMemberName` is useful for property setters:

```
string _test;
public string Test
{
    get { return _test; }
    set
    {
        _test = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // will pass "Test" as propertyName
    }
}
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Calling this from some other place obviously doesn't make sense, e.g.:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
   ...
   OnPropertyChanged(); // will pass "SomeMethod", huh? 
}
```

View will receive this notification, but will do nothing.

Hint: you can also pass empty string `""` if you want to update **all** properties, this will equally works in your case (or if you make `Count` also property and want to bind to it, then just one notification with `""` update both `Results` and `Count` in the view).